# Will updating any field in base table cause updating will all rows of the indexed view rows?

Tags: sql-server

Will updating any field in base table cause the auto maintain of the indexed view, even this field isn't included in the definition of the the indexed view?

Or even worse, will all rows of the indexed view be rewritten or will only the rows that are affected be updated?

Comment: This is probably better asked on [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com), however, an index is only updated if it's effected. So an Index on a Column `DateUpdated` that includes the column `Price` and `Currency` won't be effected if you change the value of the column `ProductName`.

Comment: Worth noting, as well, that as a `CLUSTERED INDEX` is always a covering index, it will always be effected when a DML statement is made against a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it only updates when it needs to. Here's an example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.TestValueOnly;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Test;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    TestID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_Test PRIMARY KEY,
    TestName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ValueToChange int NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT dbo.Test (TestName, ValueToChange)
VALUES ('Hello', 12),
       ('There', 14),
       ('And', 16),
       ('Again', 18);
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.TestValueOnly
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT TestID, ValueToChange 
FROM dbo.Test;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_dbo_TestValueOnly
ON dbo.TestValueOnly (TestID);
GO
```

Now look at the query plan of these two queries:

```
UPDATE dbo.Test 
SET TestName = 'Changed' 
WHERE TestID = 14;

UPDATE dbo.Test 
SET ValueToChange = 17 
WHERE TestID = 14;
```

[image]

The first just updates the base table as expected and doesn't touch the indexed view. The second hits the indexed view as well, again as expected.

Comment: After executing the second update command in this example, Sql server will remove all rows from the TestValueOnly view and insert again all rows from the Test table to the TestValueOnly view or update the TestValueOnly view just like Test table with "TestID = 14" condition

Comment: It's only the affected rows

Comment: If you try it and hover over the operators in the query plan, you can see the predicates being used.